# Screens for Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, translation, screenshot, windows-phone-store

I have just completed my new Windows Phone application. Now I want to add it to the store. My problem is, the app is translated into 34 languages and I have to provide screens for each of theese languages. Whenever I want to change the Culture of my Phone, I have to restart it - it takes too much time. My other idea was to change the culture of a running thread in the code but I could not find a working solution. Can you help me with this? I dont want to spend two days on doing screens for the store. o you have any other idea I could achieve this or could you provide some code that works on WP7 which changes the culture?

Comment: I only have 5 languages in my app, but I concur: manually making all those screenshots is PITA.

Comment: Btw, is it required to upload language specific screenshots? Why not create the important ones and use English for the rest? Another way would ask your beta testers/translators to do the work for you.

Comment: The app will not pass the Store certyfication if the screens are not translated. If you have some text content(which comes from user) in your app I also suggest you to notice it in a note for Store Testers, if you don't want to translate it. It happend that my app was rejested, because I had some example data in english. If I leave such a note, it's allways ok. - I'v been doing it already for win8

Comment: About manually making screens. It's not that bad, but yea, all together with publishing the app, sometimes it is about a day of work or even more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to change current culture:

```
 CultureInfo currentCulture = new CultureInfo("Culture_Code");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture ;
```

Comment: It does not work on Windows Phone 7.8. It changes the culture but when I restart the app the culture has it's old value.

Comment: when you change the culture from application then just save the culture code in isolated storage . When you restart the application just check culture code in Isolated storage in launching event in app.xaml.cs.If Isolated storage has culture code apply that by using above code.

Comment: You can use this code .private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("CulCode"))
            {
                CultureInfo currentCulture = new CultureInfo("Culture_Code"); Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture ;
            }}

Answer (score 1):

You can change culture, but you can't force UI to update it automatically. So, you should write some code to change controls localization at runtime. Basically, there will be the one function that updates controls with selected Culture.

Comment: So navigating to another page should do the thing? It doesn't, thats why this whole question :(

Comment: No, navigate would not help. App should restart to apply it. [Check this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/10b722b3-6c19-4ece-bb7f-27d4bd291235/changing-application-language-at-runtime?forum=winappswithcsharp) of XAML developer. Do this fuction by hands - it's not hard at all.

Comment: Hm, how could I change controls localization at runtime? Generally, changing the culture works only for the current instnce of the application. After restart, the culture has it's old value in WP7.

Comment: Yes, you can't change culture and save this state. However, you can try to save this value to the IsolatedStorageSettings and apply it at the each app activation.

Comment: It seems like app activation is a little bit too late. Even if I put it in App Constructor, it doesn't work. Generally, I have already done the screens by hand, but I think it would be nice to find a proper solution.